# Jquery DataTable checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable with two checkbox columns with a checkall checkbox for each column in the table header. I am looping through all the checkboxes in the datatable for every change event on a checkbox to make sure the checkAll checkbox is checked/unchecked which results in a lag when user checks a checkbox.

Below is the code snippet. Please let me know if there any other way I can do this to improve the performance.

```
ntfcTable.$('.ntfcInd')
            .change(
                    function() {
                        let counterNtfcCh = 0;
                        for (let i = 0; i < ntfcTableNodes.length; i++) {
                            if (ntfcTable.$('input[type="checkbox"][id="ntfcInd[' + i + ']"]').is(":checked") === true) {
                                counterNtfcCh++;
                            }
                        }
                        counterNtfcCh === ntfcTableNodes.length ? ntfcCheckAll.prop("checked", true)
                                : ntfcCheckAll.prop("checked", false);
                        checkBoxState = true;
                    });
```

Comment: Would be better if you can provide the snippet of the datatable, so that we can experiment with it.. Interesting question btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help. I am assuming that ntfcTable is a jQuery object. You don't need to search ntfcTable every time you loop through the table. The first line will grab all checkboxes in the table. jQuery objects have a length property so they can actually be looped over. This should work as long as you are not adding and removing checkboxes on the fly.

```
var ntfcTableNodes = ntfcTable.$('input[type="checkbox"]');
ntfcTableNodes.change(
                    function() {
                        let counterNtfcCh = 0;

                        for (let i = 0; i < ntfcTableNodes.length; i++) {
                            let checkNode = ntfcTableNodes[i];
                            if ( checkNode.is(":checked") === true ) {counterNtfcCh++;}
                        }
                        counterNtfcCh === ntfcTableNodes.length ? ntfcCheckAll.prop("checked", true)
                                : ntfcCheckAll.prop("checked", false);
                        checkBoxState = true;
                    });
```

Comment: Hi Jason, The above code  will only return the checkbox elements of the current page.
"ntfcTable.find('input[type="checkbox"]');" Since I am using a jquery datatable, I may not be able to use it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any DataTables experience and didn't realize they remove the data from the DOM so standard jQuery calls like find will not work. I went over their documentation and changed the first line to use their API. 
.find() needs to be .$()

Comment: Thank you Jason, I also made a small tweak to the code checkNode.checked === true :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though, the question is marked 'Answered' to those, who may face that same problem, solution, for which OP has requested, basically, boils down to one nice and neat one-liner:

```
const ifAllChecked = col => dataTable.rows().nodes().toArray().every(row => $(row).find(`td:eq(${col}) [type="checkbox"]`).is(':checked'));
```

Following is the brief **DEMO** of how it can be done:

```js
//define source data
const srcData = [
 {city: 'Kyiv', visited: true, enjoyed: true},
 {city: 'Istanbul', visited: true, enjoyed: true},
 {city: 'Moscow', visited: true, enjoyed: false},
 {city: 'Nicosia', visited: true, enjoyed: true},
 {city: 'New York', visited: false, enjoyed: false},
 {city: 'Cairo', visited: true, enjoyed: true}
];
//define datatables object
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 'tp',
  pageLength: 3,
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'city', data: 'city'},
    {
      title: 'visited',
      data: 'visited',
      render: (data, type, row, meta) => `<input type="checkbox" colindex="${meta.col}" ${data ? 'checked' : ''} style="float:right;margin-right:28px" class="regularchckbx"></input>`
    },
    {
      title: 'enjoyed',
      data: 'enjoyed',
      render: (data, type, row, meta) => `<input type="checkbox" colindex="${meta.col}" ${data ? 'checked' : ''} style="float:right;margin-right:28px" class="regularchckbx"></input>`
    },
  ]
});
//essential part of the solution OP was looking for
const ifAllChecked = col => dataTable.rows().nodes().toArray().every(row => $(row).find(`td:eq(${col}) [type="checkbox"]`).is(':checked'));
//put 'check all' checkboxes into header
$(dataTable.columns([1,2]).header()).append(`<input type="checkbox" class="allchecked" style="float:right;margin-right:20px"></input>`);
//set initial header checkboxes state
[1, 2].forEach( col => dataTable.column(col).header().querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked = ifAllChecked(col));
//listen for changes and adjust 'check-alls'
$('#mytable').on('click', '.regularchckbx', function(){
 dataTable.column($(this).attr('colindex')).header().querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked = ifAllChecked($(this).attr('colindex'));
});
//check/uncheck all
$('.allchecked').on('click', function(){
 let col = dataTable.column($(this).closest('th')).index();
 let state = this.checked;
 dataTable.rows().every(function(){
  this.node().querySelector(`[colindex="${col}"]`).checked = state;
 });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="mytable"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the checkboxes, you can just check the length of the checked checkboxes like this:

```js
alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

Or for you case, it's like this:

```
if(ntfcTable.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == ntfcTableNodes.length)
```