# How to add a textbox in a dynamically created datatable and save to the database using ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, datatable

I am new to using a datatable; I have a datatable where I want to add a textbox for each row and on button click event I want to save it to  the database with respective textbox to its particular id.

This is my datatable

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var empid = '@ViewBag.empid';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "/HRValidation/LoadInsuranceNominee",
                data: "id=" + empid,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#insurancetable').dataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { "data": null, "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<input type="checkbox" name="chkSelect" id="' + full.employeeInsuranceId + '" value="' + full.employeeInsuranceId + '">'; }},
                            { 'data': 'employeeInsuranceId' },
                            { 'data': 'employeeId' },
                            { 'data': 'insurance_Nomiee_Name' },
                            { 'data': 'insurance_Nomiee_Gender_Name' },
                            { 'data': 'insurance_Nomiee_Relationship_Name' },
                            { 'data': 'insurance_Nomiee_DOB_String' },
                            { 'data': 'relationship_Comments' }
                            
                        ],
                        //autofill: true,
                        //select: true,
                        //responsive: true,
                        //destroy: true,
                        //scrollY: true,
                        //scrollX: true,
                    })
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am stuck after this part - any help will be appreciated

Comment: "_on button click event_" - What button(s) are you referring to? There are none in the code you show us. Can you edit your question to provide more of a [mre] - and with some sample JSON data from the Ajax call?

Comment: Also take a look at answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783706/12567365) which make use of the DataTables [`rows().nodes()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()) API function.